# how to use the same array in different if-else statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

is there any error with my code? because whenever i use the sorting and view button, the number shown in the array is zero as in "0", but when i put/use the showMessageDialog within the if-else statement that i used to put some numbers is correct.. please help me.. btw sorry for my bad english..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Prog extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton sort = new JButton("Sort");
    private JButton view = new JButton("View");
    private JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
    private JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    private JLabel end = new JLabel("Assignment Passed by: Kevin Sagun");

    public Prog(){
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,400);
        setResizable(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Assignment po namin :)");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

        add(enter);
        add(sort);
        add(view);
        add(exit);
        add(end);

        sort.addActionListener(this);
        view.addActionListener(this);
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();

        int[] num=new int [5];
        int x, y, temp;
        String[] str = new String[5];

        if(source == enter){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter Your Five Numbers: ");

            for(x=0;x < num.length;x++) {
                num[x]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number "+(x+1)+":");
                num[x]=Integer.parseInt(str[x]);
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,num[0]+"IT "+num[1]+"IT "+num[2]+"IT "+num[3]+"IT "+num[4]+"IT ");

        }

        if(source == view){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,num[0]+"IT "+num[1]+"IT       "+num[2]+"IT "+num[3]+"IT "+num[4]+"IT ");
        }

        if (source == sort) {
            for (y=0;y < num.length-1;y++) {    
                for (x=0;x < num.length-1;x++) {
                    if (num[x+1] < num[x]) {
                        temp=num[x];
                        num[x]=num[x+1];
                        num[x+1]=temp;}
                }
            }
        }

        if(source == exit){
            System.exit(0);
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Prog frame = new Prog();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't compile your code but I think one bug is here:

```
if(source == enter){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter Your Five Numbers: ");
        for(x=0;x<num.length;x++){
            num[x]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number "+(x+1)+":");
```

which should be:

```
if(source == enter){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter Your Five Numbers: ");
        for(x=0;x<num.length;x++){
            str[x]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number "+(x+1)+":");
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Time you click the View Button, the whole event is triggered again, and all it's local instances are recreated! that's why array holds Zero or NULL value..

Answer (score 0):

You will never have elements in your array when `source==view` because you don't fill the array before you show it.  You only fill the array when `source==enter` and `source==sort` and then reinitialize it on the next action.  You must fill your array within the `if(source == view)` block.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `int[]num=new int [5];`, you're doing so inside the method meaning it is a *local* variable.  It seems that you're assigning it correctly save for your line:

```
num[x]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number "+(x+1)+":");
```

I'm guessing you meant:

```
str[x]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number "+(x+1)+":");
```

In order to retain the changes, it needs to become a class member, meaning you should put it on the outside of the method (generally near the top).  Your class would then become:

```
public class Prog extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private int[] num=new int [5];

    // ...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();

        int x, y, temp;
        String[] str = new String[5];
        // int[] num=new int [5];

        // ...
     }

     // ...
}
```

Try it and you'll see that the changes are retained!

Comment: thanks! i didnt knew that i should assign int from the outside.. thanks alot :D